# Disable Button submit when over the due date

Tags: php

```
<?php
      include('connect.php');

        $sql= mysql_query('SELECT * FROM lecturer WHERE id="'.$_GET['id'].'"',$con) or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      echo '<table width="511" border="0" align="center">
      <tr><td>Lecturer Name<td>:<td><input type="text" name="name" value="'.$row['lecturername'].'" size="40" required title="Name"/></td></td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td>Lecturer ID<td>:<td><input type="text" name="id" size="40" value="'.$row['id'].'" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" required title="Student ID"/></td></td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td>Title Assignment<td>:<td><input type="text" name="title" size="40" required title="Title Assignment"/></td></td></td>
      </tr>

      <tr><td>Due Date Submit<td>:<td><input type="text" name="duedate" id="popupDatepicker" size="40" required/></td></td></td></td></tr>
      <tr><td>File Upload<td>:<td><input name="uploaded_file" type="file" required title="Assignment Upload"/>
              <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" /></td></td></td></tr>
              <tr><td><td><td><input type="submit" name="Upload" value="Send"/></td></tr>
      </table>';
      }
      ?>
```

like this..when assignment out of date..the button disable to upload that assignment..
How can i set the date

Comment: I am trying to read your mind.

Comment: @HddnTHA Don't do it man, just don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the due date in the database. Then fetch it and compare it to the current date with PHP’s `date_default_timezone_set()` and `date()` functions and a simple `if` construct.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php